# Unity photon engine namespace errors

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

i am currently coding a game in unity with multiplayer. I set it up with a tutorial but only got errors.

This is the Video:
[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VX6VGcQTY5E)

And this are the
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBVmK.png)

This is my code

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Pun;
using UnityEngine.Realtime;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Manager : MonoBehaviourPunCallBacks
{
    public InputField playername;
    public Button playbutton;
    void Start()
    {
        playbutton.interactable = true;
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings();
        PhotonNetwork.AutomaticallySyncScene = true;
    }


    void Update()
    {
        string playerNameText = playername.text;
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRandomRoom();
    }
    public override void OnJoinRandomFailed(short returnCode, string message)
    {
        RoomOptions roomOps = new RoomOptions();
        roomOps.IsVisible = true;
        roomOps.IsOpen = true;
        PhotonNetwork.NickName = playername.text;
        string roomName = "Room" + Random.Range(0, 1000);
        PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(roomName, roomOps);
    }
    public override void OnJoinRoom()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel(1);
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Sure its UnityEngine.Pun?

Comment: Nope im new with photon

Comment: Well. Id suggest thats where youve gone wrong. Dont just blindly follow some tutorial. Read up on the tools used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the namespaces:

```
using UnityEngine.Pun;
using UnityEngine.Realtime;
```

To this:

```
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
```